# How can i fix the image along the path

Tags: adobe-illustrator, corel-draw

How can i fix the image along the path, I want to have 10-12 image in circular path. The logo should bend and adjust the shape of the circle and copies of 10-12. With the vector or text (fit to path) we can adjust with the path, How it work with image. Any suggestion or help.[image]

Try with this logo
[image]

Comment: Make it a brush

Comment: @joojaa Thanks, how it will work in coreldraw

Comment: Ancient Corel Draw had "Envelope". With it one could bend the logo. The rest can be rotated copies. Check does Envelope still exist. (sorry, I do not have a version that can be run in current Windows)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Illustrator, a simple **Pattern Brush** will work. Merely drag the art to the **Brush Panel** and choose `Pattern Brush` when asked, then just click `OKAY`. Draw a circle, and click the brush you just made.

[image]

If you want a bit of spacing between the iterations, extend the no-fill, no-stroke, rectangle in the brush artwork and then update the brush in the **Brush Panel** by holding the <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd> key down as you drag new artwork on top of the existing brush in the **Brush Panel**.

[image]

The only way to control the amount of iterations is to adjust either the size of the circle, or the size of the brush.

If you double-click the brush artwork in the **brush Panel** you can adjust the scale of the brush. Reducing the scale of the brush will allow for more iterations.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detail answer